# Finding parameters of a system of non-linear equations in R using BB package

Tags: r, statistics, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression

I am trying to solve a system of equation to find parameters `(x[1] and x[2])` using BB package but R outputs Unsuccessful convergence precisely it is:

```
Iteration:  0   ||F(x0)||:  469.829 
iteration:  10  ||F(xn)|| =   0.5105992 
iteration:  20  ||F(xn)|| =   0.05530002 

$`par`
[1] 26.2772128 -0.9905601

$residual
[1] 0.01809358

$fn.reduction
[1] 664.413

$feval
[1] 31

$iter
[1] 25

$convergence
[1] 3

$message
[1] "Failure: Error in function evaluation"

Warning message:
In dfsane(par = p0, fn = f3) : Unsuccessful convergence.

Simburr.f1 <- function(n, tau) {
  u=runif(n)
  x<- runif(n)
  lambda = exp(1+x)
  y= (1/(u^(1/lambda))-1)^(1/tau)
  y
}

y = Simburr.f1(300,0.5)
x = runif(300)

f3 <- function(x) { 
  n=300
  x1 <- x[1] 
  x2 <- x[2]
  F <- rep(NA, 2)
  F[1] <- n/sum(log(1+y^(x[1])))
  F[2] <- n/-sum(log(y))+(x[2]+1)*sum((log(y)*y^x[1])/(1+y^x[1]))
  return(F) 
} 
p0 <- c(0.5,1) 
dfsane(par=p0, fn=f3)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly so it can be read

Comment: are you looking for `nls`? this is the non-linear function in r used to estimate parameters

Comment: I know NLS. But i want to solve this problem with the BB package

Comment: Not really familiar with nls when it comes to two system  of non-linear equation.

Comment: I don't understand. `dfsane` solves systems of nonlinear equations of the form `F(x)=0`. But how can `300/... = 0`? What are you trying to solve?